# Outlook addin page cannot show up in F12Choosers

Tags: outlook-addin

We build an Outlook addin and trying to test it on all platforms.
It works on IE and Edge, but not in Windows native Outlook client. The button shows up, but after clicking on it, there is a message "[Our Addin] is working on our request" keeps staying there with a spinner in front of it."

We are trying to debug it using [F12Chooser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).
But no matter we launch this tool before or after launching our addin, our addin page cannot show up in the chooser.

Have been searching this issue on the Internet for quite a while, but cannot find any related posts. Need some experts help.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information. Thanks!